# VMWare Host Processor Status persistent

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtualhost, central-processing-unit

We have a new Host that we just added and put a new VM on. There is a red exclamation point with the error Host processor status. It says to check the Hardware status tab for more details but there is not much there. This is a Dell PowerEdge R730. The VM is low on resources. The CPU usage is never spiking over 80% from what I can tell in VMWare performance. Can someone please help me find the issue? I want to avoid a physical server crash and make sure all the processors are performing properly or there is not a bigger issue here. Thanks for any help on this!

Comment: I would start small checking OpenManage for hardware warning messages. What ESXi version are you running by the way? I heard there were some similar issues in old ESXi versions.

Comment: I will download OpenMange now and add that to see if there is anything that can tell me. Thanks. BTW the version is: ESXi 6.0

Comment: Which Update version? There's a quite serious bug in 6.0, so I'd recommend that you upgrade to 6.0U2 as soon as possible if you're running 6.0 or 6.0U1

Comment: I will check out what version we are on. Do you have a resource that I can look at to see the information about this bug?